# Migrate from weblogic to tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, weblogic

My application is currently working fine on weblogic. But due to upgrade the application, I want to use spring boot and embedded tomcat. I have a `JndiTemplate` bean such as:

```
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">${java.naming.factory.initial}</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">${java.naming.provider.url}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This template is a helper to lookup for jndi objects like datasources and jms.
As you know the factory is `weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory` and url is `t3://SERVER:PORT` when we are on weblogic. but speaking of tomcat I dont know how to configure this template.

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat is not a Java EE container like Weblogic. If you really want to keep using JNDI, have a look at TomEE.

Personally, I would let Spring manage the database connection. The advantage of using a framework like Spring is that it takes alot of responsibilities away from the container your application is running in, like eg. the database connection.

Spring Boot autoconfigures a DataSource by looking at:

- your `application.yml` for the JDBC url and username/password
- your `pom.xml` to see which database driver it will use (Spring Boot can also derive that from your JDBC url, but you'll have to add the driver library)

There's really nothing more to do.

You can now autowire the `DataSource` or use Spring's `JdbcTemplate` to avoid alot of boilerplate code.

Answer (score 1):

This can be configured using Config files using @Bean annotation to initialize the TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory . Please see below code snippet which might be helpful.  Below is one of the format that needs to be updated as per your need.

```
@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatFactory() {

    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(Tomcat tomcat) {
            tomcat.enableNaming();
            return super.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(tomcat);
        }

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory#postProcessContext(org.apache.catalina.Context)
         */
        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            ContextResource resource = new ContextResource();
            resource.setName("your_app_DS_name");
            resource.setType("your_app_property");
            resource.setProperty("driverClassName", "your_app_Drive");
            resource.setProperty("factory", "your_app_factory_property_details");
//similarly configure other needed and dependent properties.
            context.getNamingResources().addResource(resource);

        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But the fact is that this tomcat should expose jndi objects.